# Wifi disconnects after sleep and after reboot Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, suspend, intel-wireless

I'm an Ubuntu newbie and I'm enjoying everything apart from the wonky WiFi.

After sleep, or after reboot I often lose my WiFi connection and can't get it back (WiFi card works in Windows). I've searched through the forums and sometimes the following works

```
iwconfig wlan0
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off 

sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf<<<"options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypt o=1 bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0"
```

but often they don't. It's all quite random and I've no idea what is wrong.

I have a Thinkpad T520i and I think it has a Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] WiFi card. I'm using 14.04 Ubuntu LTS.

I don't know what else to add here. If you could help that would be great. If you could explain it in simple terms that a golden retriever could understand that would be even better.

Edit: still having problems. I've noticed that sometimes (occasionally) putting it to sleep and waking it up seems to work.

Comment: Does the wireless restart if you do: `sudo service network-manager restart`?

Comment: Thank you :-) Just tried this, it doesn't seem to work sadly.

Comment: Did you fix it? Having similar issue.

Comment: Upgrading Ubuntu worked. I'm on 18.04 now and all is fine on this front